# How to animate a rolling rectangle

Tags: css, rotation, css-animations, css-transforms

I'd like to animate a rectangle to roll from the left of the screen to the right of the screen. Please notice that the transform-origin point should not be in the center of the rectangle, but in the bottom-right corner, so that it doesn't overpass the "hr" line or bounce in any way.

This is what I have achieved untill now, but I'd like it to move continuously untill it gets to the right edge of the screen:

```css
hr {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 135px;
  height: 135px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  animation-name: move;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: 0;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the transform origin as you go :

```css
hr {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 135px;
  height: 135px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  animation-name: move;
  animation-duration: 12s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: 0;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  }
  25.1% {
    transform:   translate(100%, 100%) rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: top right;
  }
  50% {
    transform:  translate(100%, 100%) rotate(180deg);
    transform-origin: top right;
  }
  50.1% {
    transform: translate(300%, 100%) rotate(180deg);
    transform-origin: left top;
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(300%, 100%) rotate(270deg);
    transform-origin: left top;
  }
  75.1% {
    transform: translate(400%, 0%) rotate(270deg);
    transform-origin: left bottom;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(400%, 0%) rotate(360deg);
    transform-origin: left bottom;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>TEST</div>
<hr>
```

Comment: i was going with this configuration at first and go mad finding the correct transalation :) great one !

Answer (score 3):

Interesting, I would consider adding a translation and the trick is to switch fastly between two states to be able to continue the move.

You are rotating your element with **90deg** which is equivalent in your case to a **translation by the width** of the element if we only consider the final state so switching fastly between both situation won't be visible and thus you can rotate your element again and repeat the same trick until your reach the needed position.

```css
hr {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 135px;
  height: 135px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  animation-name: move;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: 0;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  25.01% {
    transform: translateX(calc(1 * 135px)) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(calc(1 * 135px)) rotate(90deg);
  }
  50.01% {
    transform: translateX(calc(2 * 135px)) rotate(0deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(calc(2 * 135px)) rotate(90deg);
  }
  75.01% {
    transform: translateX(calc(3 * 135px)) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(calc(3 * 135px)) rotate(90deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<hr>
```

Comment: @VXp pay attention with the values ... using very small value like you did won't work in all the cases .. it's not working on chrome when tested

Comment: Wrong, working just fine with me, also Chrome. Current values are not appropriate.

Comment: @VXp strange ... it tested and it's not working for me .. i also faced the same issue before when i tried to use values under 0.1 ... well i have decreased them to 0.1 instead of 0.5 i think it's better .. and i will see what is happening on my side

Comment: I ran it multiple times without any problems whatsoever, strange indeed.

Comment: @VXp well it's working fine now :/ not sure what was the issue .. maybe a browser bug that create a kind of flickering

Comment: Could be, saw it once at first but then no more, probably has to "store" it the first time which can cause flickering.